# Extjs Pivot Grid Row Numbers

Tags: extjs, pivot-grid

In the kitchen sink classic pivot grid configuration plugin example there are row numbers in the first column of the grid.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's the link to the example
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#configurable-pivot-grid

I tried setting rowNumbers to true but it didn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

rownumberer is column type. you must use it in columns

```js
columns: [
    {xtype: 'rownumberer'},
    {text: "Company", flex: 1, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company'},
]
```

**Edited:**

sorry for wrong answer. it was for ordinary grid. to show rowNumbeber on pivot grid set

```js
selModel: {
        type: 'spreadsheet'
    },
```

Comment: That's for a regular grid it doesn't work for a pivot grid